# How to bind the data from the API Model to XAML labels in Xamarin

Tags: c#, api, xaml, xamarin, binding

I am building a recipe app for a uni project. I have found an API and Im getting the results using the MVC Format, not really good at programming. I have an API Class, a Controller and then the data being sent to a var on MainPage, I am having trouble binding it to the labels in MainPage.
I am going to post the screenshots of the classes so you guys can understand.

[image]

This class has all the fields provided from the API, however since I am only testing... I only have 2 fields in my model class only getting the name of the food and the image source, as seen in the picture below.
[image]

[image]
This is the APIController class which handles everything and gets called in MainPage.

MainPage calls the SearchRecipe method which gets the data from the controller and puts it in "var result"
[image]

Now, I can just make a listview in mainpage and put the result in the listview like "lstName.ItemSource =  result" but I want it to put data separetly and not grouped.

This is how my MainPage xaml looks like,
[image]

If someone could help me figure out whatever it is I need to fix/add/remove to get the data to be shown in each label separetly by Binding would be really helpful! Thank you so much for reading.

Comment: please do NOT post code as images.  You need to assign a BindingContext, and you can only bind to public properties.  `apiModel` is not a public property

Comment: what do you mean "I want it to put data separetly and not grouped" ? Could you get the data ( var result) correctly ? if yes ,you just need bind the reuslt to your listview ItmenSource,(if you bind it in your code behind,you don't need to bind it in your xaml again)

Comment: Can you please post result listview and expain what is it you want clearly?

Comment: Hey Guys sorry for replying late. @Jason Im extremely sorry for posting code as image, I thought it would help explain my program. I dont know how to bind the properties in my apiModel class to the labels in front end, Im fairly new to binding and I find it a little difficult. [Leo] Honestly I thought it would work, but when I put the var result in a listview, it didnt display the result, instead it displayed the name of my file. I wanted to bind separate properties to separate labels, like the name property would bind to the label name. Instead of all the data in 1 listview all grouped.

Comment: Hey @Sümeyya, I cant really post result listview as their are no results showing yet. I put a breakpoint to see if it was getting the data in var result which it is, but it does not show the data if I put it in a listview. https://i.imgur.com/sEkrt0R.png here the result can be seen with the data and the code above that I am using to put the result in a listview but it shows results on the app like this. https://i.imgur.com/j8ZzJUa.png

Comment: Nevermind Guys, I ended up fixing it and binding it I think.
I named the listView in xaml to FoodResults. In CS, instead of pushing the data into a var result... I made a new list called apiModel and putting the data into their, then sending apiModel data into the listView. https://i.imgur.com/xUNxQgz.png
Now I can control what I want to show in each label instead everything in a list showing at once. if that is what binding is. This is the result https://i.imgur.com/NA492T9.png
Please let me know if that is what binding is, if that is it I have found the solution, thanks for your answers!